# mysql issue when reading in Date type from .txt file with str_to_date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqldatatypes, dml

I have been given the task of reading in a .txt file into a mySQL table. 
Here is what I did.

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON(PIDM INT, FNAME VARCHAR(20), LNAME VARCHAR(20), SSN INT(8), DOB DATE, GENDER    CHAR(2));

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/pathtoTextFile'
    INTO TABLE PERSON
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ', '
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (PIDM, FNAME, LNAME, SSN, @DATE, GENDER)
    SET DOB = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE, '%m-%d-%Y');
```

But I get several warnings from doing this. 
including:

```
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                         |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '12/14/1957' for function str_to_date |
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '01/13/1969' for function str_to_date |
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'SSN' at row 3                    |
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '02/14/1976' for function str_to_date |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'SSN' at row 4           |
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '03/12/1989' for function str_to_date
```

I haven't been able to figure out why I get an invalid date from the str_to_date function/method. 
This is supposed to be a learning excercise but I have been at it for like 2 hours and haven't gotten anywhere. Does anyone have any tips or any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

P.S. The purpose is not to change the .txt file for it to work, but to be able to handle incorrect inputs.

Comment: did you consider the characters in between the month day year? you have specified dash, but the errors show slash

Comment: Funny thing I was sure I had tried switching them to '/' but apparently I didn't and when I went back it worked. Thanks. Here is another question, how do you specify the value of NULL if SSN is not 8 places long?

Comment: `case when length(ssn) <> 8 then NULL else SSN end`; but you should signify this question is answered by ticking the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the source data but if there is a mixture of MM/DD/YYYY and MM-DD-YYYY you could replace the unwanted delimiter with the wanted delimiter, then convert to date.

Note: because Month First and Day First formats are "ambiguous" (e.g. 7/8/2014 could be a date in July or August) they should be avoided whenever possible.